# exponential generating function of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: combinatorics

Hey just had a quick question related to coming up with an explicit formula for $a_n$ with relation to $F(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. I know to compute such a function I have to use the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to obtain the summation of $(n+1)x^n$, but I am unsure how to rewrite this summation in terms of the exponential generating function, in which I can then use the coefficients to obtain $a_n$. I know it will probably end up being a shift in the index that makes such $a_n$ possible, with the stipulation that $a_0=0$, and $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n+n!$ for $n\ge0$.

Comment: To sum up, you are asking for the sum of the series $\sum\limits_n(n+1)x^n/n!$, right?

Comment: yes i need to write this sum in terms of an exponential generating function, and then take the coefficients of the sum in that form to determine a_n that satisfy the above values of a_n.

Comment: I thought I had finally managed to understand what you were asking but your comment lost me again.

Comment: 8.27 of this is very similar to what I am asking to find https://sp.eths.k12.il.us/aginr/indstudy/Class%20Documents/hw11-solns.pdf

Comment: Your question is confused. Apparently you want something like $(1-x)^{-2}$ to _be_ the exponential generating function, but the real question is to solve the given recurrence (maybe using such a g.f.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geqslant0}(n+1)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}n\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\stackrel{n=k+1}{=}\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}+\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=(x+1)\mathrm e^x$$

Comment: does this satisfy a_0=0 and a_n+1=(n+1)a_n + n!? the reason for the summation is to find an a_n such that these hold true.

Comment: We still do not know what are these coefficients $a_n$ you are talking about. You seem to be thinking about a specific context but I cannot fathom what this context is.

Comment: finding a closed formula for a_n given a_0=0 and a_(n+1)=(n+1)a_n +n! with n>=o. the process of this is writing the recurrence as an exponential generating function, with A(X)=the defenition of a generating function. when you write the second recurrence as an exponential generating function, then take the summation of both sides you obtain A(x)= (1/((1-x)^2)). typically with exponential functions you'd do partial fractions to find out the coefficients of (1/((1-x)^2)), then rewrite (1/((1-x)^2) as a sum of the two partial fractions, and then rewrite those in terms of the exponential power...

Comment: function and then the a_n coefficients of x^(n) in A(x) is what I am determining